# I want to uninstall notepad++ but in the terminal I get the message notepad-plus plus not installed. What can I do?

Tags: command-line, apt, execute-command

The app is installed and functional but I wanna uninstall it. I've tried through the command line but I get the error message saying "notepad-plus plus" not installed.

Comment: what exact command did you issue to uninstall? And do you remember how you installed it ? Do you notice there is a `-` missing in the error msg?

Answer (score 1):

Please use software center to remove software